# Perl module run under Linux and Win32

Tags: linux, windows, perl, multiplatform

I've a perl module which needs to run within both Win32 and Linux OSes. This module employs Win32::Process::List to avoid concurrency issues with a 3rd party application under Win32, and has no equivalent requirement when run under Linux.

So far, I've managed to have two copies of the same module, with Win32-specific stuff commented out for the Linux version - and I'm obviously not happy with this error-prone approach.

It is clear that win-specific stuff does not "make install" in Linux. I've tried a softer approach in my code with `require Win32::Process::List;` instead of `use Win32::Process::List;`, the former giving the advantage of passing `perl -c mymodule` - however still failing in regular use.

Thus my question: apart from mantaining two distinct code bases, is there a more robust way to approach such situations?

Comment: You should look at how [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec) is implemented.

Answer (score 4):

How about using the [`if module`](https://metacpan.org/module/if), which allows you to `use` a module according to compile-time conditions.

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', 'Win32::Process::List';
```

The `$^O` built-in variable gives the name of the operating system, and is always `MSWin32` for any Windows system.

Comment: ++ Good point, didn't know one could insert conditions within the **use** statement. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a normal Perl `if` statement. [`if` is a module](https://metacpan.org/module/if) that does the magic for you with a nice syntax